# Terminal only shows > symbol when I enter this find command

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, find

I want to delete all .ppm and .png files under current directory. So after checking some web pages about the usage of "find" command on the Internet, I typed the command below:

```
find . -type f \( -iname ".png" -o -iname ".ppm \) -exec rm {} \;
```

but the Terminal just showed a

```
>
```

and did not do anything. What was wrong with it?

Comment: Since you had an argument list too long issue, see also [Renaming large number of image files with bash](//askubuntu.com/q/1038101)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to close the quoted string with a `"` after `".ppm`.

The `>` you see is Bash's *secondary prompt*, as defined by the `$PS2` environment variable. You get it when you input a command fragment that is supposed to continue (like e.g. because it has an unclosed quoted string or a missing `done` or `fi` keyword...) but press Enter to make a line break.

Another thing is that `-iname ".png"` would only (case insensitively) match files with the *exact* name ".png". What you want is to match all files ending with ".png", so the condition must be `-iname "*.png"` instead. Same for ".ppm" of course.

So the correct `find` command would be:

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.ppm" \) -exec rm {} \;
```

However, I'd usually recommend dry-running it without the `-exec rm {} \;` first and check the list of files again for correctness, before actually letting it delete stuff without further confirmation.

Also, as correctly pointed out in the comments, you can and probably should replace `-exec rm {} \;` with `-delete` to let `find` handle the deletion internally.

Comment: Note that you can use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} \;`, which is just cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `find` for this. Instead, you can run

```
rm *{.png,.ppm}
```

in the directory.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried it yet, but Argument list too long.

Comment: Have you copied and pasted it? I tested it and worked.

Comment: Of course it will work with a few images. But my directory contains more than 100,000 images.

Comment: Sorry then, didn't understand your first comment right.